# Classifier prediction results biased

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, svm, prediction

I built a classifier with 13 features ( no binary ones ) and normalized individually for each sample using scikit tool ( Normalizer().transform).

When I make predictions it predicts all training sets as positives and all test sets as negatives ( irrespective of fact whether it is positive or negative )

What anomalies I should focus on in my classifier, feature or data ???

Notes: 1) I normalize test and training sets (individually for each sample) separately.

2) I tried cross validation but the performance is same

3) I used both SVM linear and RBF Kernels

4) I tried without normalizing too. But same poor results

5) I have same number of positive and negative datasets ( 400 each) and 34 samples of positive and 1000+ samples of negative test sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're training on balanced data the fact that "it predicts all training sets as positive" is probably enough to conclude that something has gone wrong.

Try building something very simple (e.g. a linear SVM with one or two features) and look at the model as well as a visualization of your training data; follow the scikit-learn example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html

There's also a possibility that your input data has many large outliers impacting the transform process...

Comment: I will try the first suggestion. Actually I did it using MRMR technique of feature selection. But I suspect the second one that data has a lot of outliers. I assumption to create negative data-set       (which classifier fails to predict) was very large. Hence can you suggest me some techniques with practical links and resources which I can use for outlier removal. I tried it to do with Anomaly Detection technique using SVM but seems I failed there also. Please help me out.

Comment: Well, outliers can mean a lot of different things. Rather than try more sophisticated approaches, try simpler ones to figure out what's going on in your data or data preparation process. This, more than the modeling technique, is probably the root cause of what you are observing.

Comment: ok... any specific protocol or method to figure out that ( problem with data or data preparation process) ???

Answer (score 0):

Try doing feature selection on the training data (Seperately from your test/validation data). 
Feature selection on your whole dataset can easily lead to overfitting.